# Unterschied zwischen Schnelldurchlauf und Schnelldurchgang

Tags: difference, synonym

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen *[Schnelldurchlauf](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Schnelldurchlauf)* und *[Schnelldurchgang](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Schnelldurchgang)*? Der Duden gibt für beide Begriffe exakt die selbe Bedeutung an.

Intuitiv würde ich sagen:

Ersteres bezieht sich mehr auf passive Prozesse einer Maschine etc., während Zweiteres eher eine aktive Handlung (von Menschen) beschreibt.

Comment: Willkommen bei GermanSE :)

Comment: Ich würde mich deiner Intuition hier anschließen: Den Schnelldurchgang mache ich (oder macht jemand), der Schnelldurchlauf kann auch bei einer Präsentation, einer Aufzeichnung o.ä. verwendet werden.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Die beiden Wörter unterscheiden sich nur in der letzten Silbe: -lauf und -gang.
Der Lauf und der Gang sind Wörter, die einen ähnlichen Vorgang beschreiben.
Beide Wörter werden in ähnlichen Kontexten verwendet: Siehe dazu beispielsweise die vom DWDS bereitgestellten Korpora für [Schnelldurchlauf](https://www.dwds.de/?q=Schnelldurchlauf) und [Schnelldurchgang](https://www.dwds.de/?q=Schnelldurchgang&from=wb), etwa aus der Zeit.

Daher sehe ich die beiden Ausdrücke als synonym an.

Answer (score 4):

Ich sehe keinen Unterschied, auch nicht den von dir vermuteten.

Sowohl laufen als auch gehen (Lauf/Gang) beschreiben u.A. menschliche Fortbewegungsarten, die beiden unterscheiden sich nur in der angenommenen Geschwindigkeit (zumindestens im Hochdeutschen).

Da wir uns hier im übertragenen Sinnbereich bewegen, sollte der ursprünglich vorhandene Geschwindigkeitsunterschied irrelevant sein. Ich glaube nicht, dass ein *Schnelldurchlauf* schneller als ein *Schnelldurchgang* sein sollte.

Comment: Die Vermutung in Zusammenhang mit "Prozesse[n] einer Maschine" hat schon etwas für sich. Ich denke dass man bei Sachen die laufen, aber nicht gehen (etwa: ein Film, eine CD, ein Prozess oder Programm), konsequenterweise nur von einem Schnelldurch*lauf* sprechen kann.

Comment: @dlatikay Da antworte ich mal mit einem "Vollwaschgang" und einem "Rückwärtsgang". So logisch ist die Sprache nicht.